# Go: how to run tests for multiple packages?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mgo

I have multiple packages under a subdirectory under src/,
running the tests for each package with `go test` is working fine.

When trying to run all tests with `go test ./...` the tests are running but it fails..

the tests are running against local database servers, each test file has global variables with db pointers.

I tried to run the tests with `-parallel 1` to prevent contention in the db, but the tests still fail.

what can be the issue here?

EDIT: some tests are failing on missing DB entries, I completely clear the DB before and after each test. the only reason I can think of why this is happening is because of some contention between tests.

EDIT 2:

each one of my test files has 2 global variables (using mgo):

```
var session *mgo.Session
var db *mgo.Database
```

also it has the following setup and teardown functions:

```
func setUp() {
   s, err := cfg.GetDBSession()
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }

   session = s

   db = cfg.GetDB(session)

   db.DropDatabase()
}

func tearDown() {
   db.DropDatabase()

   session.Close()
}
```

each tests startup with `setUp()` and `defer tearDown()`

also cfg is:

```
package cfg

import (
    "labix.org/v2/mgo"
)

func GetDBSession() (*mgo.Session, error) {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")

    return session, err
}

func GetDB(session *mgo.Session) *mgo.Database {
    return session.DB("test_db")
}
```

EDIT 3:

I changed cfg to use a random database, the tests passed.
it seems that the tests from multiple packages are running somewhat in parallel.

is it possible to force `go test` to run everything sequentially across packages ?

Comment: What's the error message? Do you use any files? Relative paths might be wrong when `go test` is launched from a different directory.

Comment: What exactly fails? The more information you provide, the more we can help you.

Comment: To be clear: the answer to the stated question is `go test ./...`. I do it every day. You have some other question related to your specific situation, and you need to more clearly ask that question.

Comment: some tests seem to fail because of missing DB entries, I completely drop the DB before and after each test, so the only reason I can think of why this is happening when running `go test ./...` and everything passes when running a single test file is because of some contention between tests...

Comment: What do you mean by "before and after each test?" How are you implementing that? A simplified example of your tests would go a long way here.

Comment: I added some more info to the question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

apparently running `go test -p 1` runs everything sequentially (including build), I haven't see this argument in `go help test` or `go help testflag`

Comment: It's in there: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies : "-p n
 the number of programs, such as build commands or
 test binaries, that can be run in parallel.
 The default is the number of CPUs available, except
 on darwin/arm which defaults to 1."

Answer (score 21):

**Update**: As pointed out by @Gal Ben-Haim, adding the (undocumented) `go test -p 1` flag builds and tests all packages in serial. As put by the testflag usage message in the Go source code:

> -p=n: build and test up to n packages in parallel

**Old answer**:

When running `go test ./...`, the tests of the different packages are in fact run in parallel, even if you set `parallel=1` (only tests within a specific package are guaranteed to be run one at a time). If it is important that the packages be tested in sequence, like when there is database setup/teardown involved, it seems like the only way right now is to use the shell to emulate the behavior of `go test ./...`, and forcing the packages to be tested one by one.

Something like this, for example, works in Bash:

```
find . -name '*.go' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u | xargs -n1 -P1 go test
```

The command first lists all the subdirectories containing `*.go` files. Then it uses `sort -u` to list each subdirectory only once (removing duplicates). Finally all the subdirectories containing go files get fed to `go test` via `xargs`. The `-P1` indicates that at most one command is to be run at a time.

Unfortunately, this is a lot uglier than just running `go test ./...`, but it might be acceptable if it is put into a shell script or aliased into a function that's more memorable:

```
function gotest(){   find $1 -name '*.go' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u | xargs -n1 -P1 go test; }
```

Now all tests can be run in the current directory by calling:

```
gotest .
```

Comment: Oh wow, you're right - I actually checked the Go source code before posting this answer and yet somehow still didn't notice that option.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that because the packages individually pass that in this situation you are also dropping the DB before that test as well.

Therefore it sounds like the state of the DB for each package test is expected to be empty.
So between each set of the package tests the DB must be emptied.  There are two ways around this, not knowing your entire situation I will briefly explain both options:

***Option 1. Test Setup***

Add an `init()` function to the start of each package _test file which you then put processing to remove the DB.  This will be run before the `init()` method of the actual package:

```
func init() {
    fmt.Println("INIT TEST")
    // My test state initialization
    // Remove database contents
}
```

Assuming that the package also had a similar print line you would see in the output (note the stdout output is only displayed when the a test fails or you supply the `-v` option)

```
INIT TEST
INIT PACKAGE
```

***Option 2. Mock the database***

Create a mock for the database (unless that is specifically what you are testing). The mock db can always act like the DB is blank for the starting state of each test.

Comment: I added some more info to the question, isn't what I'm doing before and after each test is enough ?

Comment: Based on what you have added in your second edit, as far as my knowledge goes its seems enough. Maybe its a db server restriction getting in the way?

Comment: its just a locally installed Mongodb on Ubuntu.. I have no problems running similar tests against it with Python or Node.js.

Comment: is it possible that the tests are somehow run in parallel ?

Answer (score 0):

I used a cheap way to pick-up tests in multiple packages.

```bash
go test -v ./... -run "TestUnit?"
```

Just name your tests so they get caught:

`func TestUnitCountriesStructs(t *testing.T)`

You mentioned about needing some sort of set up and teardown for your tests.  I use [testify](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite).  In short:

```
import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/suite"
)

type ExampleTestSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
    VariableThatShouldStartAtFive int
}

// before each test
func (suite *ExampleTestSuite) SetupTest() {
    suite.VariableThatShouldStartAtFive = 5
}

func (suite *ExampleTestSuite) TestExample() {
    assert.Equal(suite.T(), 5, suite.VariableThatShouldStartAtFive)
    suite.Equal(5, suite.VariableThatShouldStartAtFive)
}

func TestUnitExampleTestSuite(t *testing.T) {
    suite.Run(t, new(ExampleTestSuite))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try out the following github repository.

https://github.com/appleboy/golang-testing

Copy `coverage.sh` to `/usr/local/bin/coverage` and change permission.

```
$ curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/appleboy/golang-testing/master/coverage.sh /usr/local/bin/coverage
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/coverage
```