# How to enforce testing order for different tests in a go framework?

Tags: go

If I have different packages and each have a test file (`pkg_test.go`) is there a way for me to make sure that they run in a particular order ?

Say `pkg1_test.go` gets executed first and then the rest.

I tried using go channels but it seems to hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't obvious, considering a `go test ./...` triggers test on all packages... but runs in parallel: see "[Go: how to run tests for multiple packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840896/6309)".

`go test -p 1` would run the tests sequentially, but not necessarily in the order you would need.

A simple script calling `go test` on the packages listed in the right expected order would be easier to do.

---

Update 6 years later: the best practice is to *not* rely on test order.
So much so [issue 28592](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28592) advocates for adding `-shuffle` and `-shuffleseed` to shuffle tests.

[CL 310033](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/310033/) mentions:

> This CL adds a new flag to the testing package and the `go test` command
> which randomizes the execution order for tests and benchmarks.
>
> This can be useful for identifying unwanted dependencies
> between test or benchmark functions.
>
> The flag is off by default.
>
> - If `-shuffle` is set to `on` then the system
>   clock will be used as the seed value.
> - If `-shuffle` is set to an integer `N`, then `N` will be used as the seed value.
>
> In both cases, the seed will be reported for failed runs so that they can reproduced later on.

Picked up for Go 1.17 (Aug. 2021) in [commit cbb3f09](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/cbb3f090477de92a7e158050803ef71a5ea825ee).

See more at "[Benchmarking with Go](https://stonecode.ca/benchmarking-with-go/)".

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack to get around this.
I named my test files as follow:

```
A_{test_file1}_test.go
B_{test_file2}_test.go
C_{test_file3}_test.go
```

The A B C will ensure they are run in order.